# RestAPI different json for list of items and item details

Tags: rest, json

I have a RestAPI with two endpoints:
/items - list of items
/items/2 - selected by id, an item details

returned json for list of items is

{ "id": "1", "name": "Max" }

returned json for item details

{ "id": "1", "name": "Max", "age": 30 }

What are pro & cons (from client perspective) for mapping the data to:

- two different models ItemList and ItemDetails
- single model but fields for item details are optionals
- model with inheritance: Item and ItemDetails inherits from Item

Comment: see [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the perspective of a user of the API,

- Inheritance is not going to bring me any real benefit. The typical use case is that I will have a list of `Item` objects and for one of them I need to have an `ItemDetails` object. I don't have the additional information that `ItemDetails` needs, so I need to request the complete `ItemDetails` object from the API anyway.

  You could argue that the new `ItemDetails` object can replace the original `Item` object in the collection, but that only makes it harder on me to determine if I need to retrieve an `ItemDetails` object or if I have one disguised as an `Item` object. That makes the code more complex, meaning more ways to introduce bugs and more testing that needs to be done. It might be easier to just maintain a cache of the `ItemDetails` objects independent of the list of `Items`.
- As for using two models or one model with optional fields, that depends on more factors like how well the data in the list-API matches the requirements for what must be shown in a list overview (single model has an advantage when you need to show more than the list-API provides). But the single model also has the complexity of determining when to ask for more details that I outlined above for the inheritance, which can be made harder if some properties really are optional.